# pycharm Error with no mistake in the value in the error

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I tried python long() on pycharm. 
to my surprise somtimes it worked and somtimes it didnt.

Heres the error

```
47282403038107662437532352993237672764098837162957292306008999337426727315883576761859649562858426653153678910738970617803055844492933792849924063437779685758693448498279910053656435887527114035456482

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/qwaszx/6436-3061/the project/cmd client.py", line 5, in     <module>
print the_project.snd_password('asadafa',99999,'127.0.0.1','/media/qwaszx/6436-3061/the project/clientfile' ,'127.0.0.1').sign_up()

  File "/media/qwaszx/6436-3061/the project/the_project.py", line 348, in __init__
self.tp.recived.update(exchange_keys(self.tp.thirdside_ip_adr,self.tp.saved,dest).recive_encryption_keys())#recieve keys for encryption

  File "/media/qwaszx/6436-3061/the project/the_project.py", line 299, in __init__
self.saved={i: long(str(saved[i]))for i in saved}

  File "/media/qwaszx/6436-3061/the project/the_project.py", line 299, in <dictcomp>
self.saved={i: long(str(saved[i]))for i in saved}

ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '47282403038107662437532352993237672764098837162957292306008999337426727315883576761859649562858426653153678910738970617803055844492933792849924063437779685758693448498279910053656435887527114035456482'
```

The first number is after doing naive long on the error number.

I tried with int() and the same thing happend (with int instead)

Do anyone have any idea?thanks

Could it be because i'm using ubuntu?

Comment: why are you calling str?

Comment: I noticed Python doesn't print the characters conflicting for long conversion if they are in the end, for example "1234567890z". Try checking if there aren't any non-digit non-whitespace characters at the end of `str(saved[i])`

Comment: i found the problem-its as as hajtos said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is that pycharm does not show the end of the str in the error if its too long.